# apt update error with ubuntu 18.10 cosmic version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.10

**Problem:  error 404 code status http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease**

***Ubuntu 18.10 cosmic*** end of life

since yesterday, apt install commands no longer work,
I tried to upgrade my system version but i got the same error of apt-get update command

```
$ apt update
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.173 80]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I forced the downgrade to change the source.list ...
I followed this article : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-downgrade-ubuntu-linux-system-to-its-previous-version

Comment: This is a bad idea. See Bart Robeyns [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1530725/413021) for the correct solution.

Answer (score 37):

The repositories are still available on http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu.
You can change them in /etc/apt/sources.list, replacing all occurences of http://archive.ubuntu.com with http://old-releases.ubuntu.com.

After that, apt-get upgrade will work again.

More info on dealing with no longer supported versions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: In addition: if you have http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu occurrences, disable them as they also don't work.
+1 for the answer.

Comment: Also works for replacing us.archive.ubuntu.com with that, thanks!  I almost can't believe ubuntu makes this required, that is a huge confusion for lay users...

Comment: I understand now that they moved archive to old-releases, but Canonical should not makes those changes. The software-properties-gtk application just can handle this change and you require users to do that manually. For a user perspective you just have a system that brokens by itself with no fair reason.

Comment: This works for me. Thanks

Comment: This answer worked for me. The chosen answer looks dangerous.

Comment: and do you want Ubuntu to be for common lay users? How the fuck I'm gonna say my dad to do that?

Comment: The LTS (Long Term Support) versions are explicitly meant for longer term support, and therefor better suited for said lay users. It does state so explicitly on the download page (https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop), but admittedly there are other ways to obtain the installation image. Still, I've always seen both LTS and non-LTS offered, which for me personally raises enough curiosity to understand the difference.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's because your Ubuntu version is out of date. That means Ubuntu does not provide security support because the system is too old. You need to disable the bad repos in your sources list and then run `apt` again.
2. `apt-update` does not upgrade your system. It only updates the repositories in your system. If you need to upgrade to another Ubuntu version, run `do-release-upgrade`. Otherwise, run `apt-upgrade -y` to upgrade system packages. Obviously, run `sudo` if you are not the `root` user.

Comment: Hello Jeremy,
Thank you for your answer,
I have to execute the 'apt -upgrade -y' command. I got this as a message with the status code 1

An upgrade from 'cosmic' to 'eoan' is not supported with this tool.
=== Command detached from window (Mon Feb 24 08:11:24 2020) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Mon Feb 24 08:11:34 2020) ===

Checking the package manager

Unable to upgrade

Comment: Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

An upgrade from 'cosmic' to 'eoan' is not supported with this tool. 
=== Command detached from window (Mon Feb 24 11:50:13 2020) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Mon Feb 24 11:50:23 2020) ===

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ubuntu 18.04 as that is close to what you have, is a Long Term Service version, and updates just fine. I update my Ubuntu machine regularly.

Comment: I can't upgrade or downgrade my version of ubuntu...

Comment: Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

An upgrade from 'cosmic' to 'eoan' is not supported with this tool. 
=== Command detached from window (Mon Feb 24 11:50:13 2020) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Mon Feb 24 11:50:23 2020) ===

Comment: (a) Why can you not use Version 18.04 LTS?  (b) What about upgrading to a newer version?